# Why the navbar is not floating to the center of the screen using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, alignment, tailwind-css, navbar

I can't understand why the navbar in align to left while i set the `margin: auto` and `justify: center` and all other necessary property. But the navbar still is not float to the center. Why ?

See the screenshot below :

[image]

Also i've attached my navbar code :

**Nabvar.jsx:**

```
return (
    <nav
      className={`
        ${styles.paddingX} w-fit flex flex-1 py-1 fixed top-5 z-20 mx-auto
        ${scrolled ? "bg-nav-gradient" : "bg-transparent"}
      `}
    >
      <div className="w-fit flex flex-1 justify-between items-center max-w-7xl mx-auto gap-10">
        <Link
          to="/"
          className="flex items-center gap-5"
          onClick={() => {
            setActive("");
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          }}
        >
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-9 h-9 object-contain" />
        </Link>

        
        {/* Day-Night Mode => Toggle Button */}
        <Box display="flex">
          <IconButton
            onClick={colorMode.toggleColorMode}
            color={colors.primary[100]}
          >
            {theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? (
              <DarkModeOutlinedIcon />
            ) : (
              <LightModeOutlinedIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Where

```
paddingX: "sm:px-16 px-6"
```

and I've removed the `ul` and `li` tags for simplicity.

I've tried almost every property but can't find what's missing. Also tried `position: relative` and it positioned the navbar to center but it was moving to top while scrolling, it's change the fixed position of navbar. So what i can do to achieve both, what i've missed, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your nav element is set to `w-fit`, i.e. `width: fit-content`.

In order for the div to centre, it needs to sit inside a full width element, so it might be worth changing the `w-fit` to a `w-full` and see if that helps.

The alternative might be to look to centre the nav element itself, depending on what else you need to happen, e.g. coloured, full-width backgrounds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not exactly... i solved the problem by adding some style property on `App.js` file. Thank you for our response